# How to Add 12 Hours to Current Date?

Tags: javascript, html

How to add 12 hours to the current display date? I want to have a promotional offer on my website, this promotional offer will close 12 hours from the current time.
People from different countries with different time slots will visit this, So it has to suffice to their time slot. How can I achieve this?

```html
<html>
<font size="+1.5"><p id="date"></p></font>
<script>
n =  new Date();
y = n.getFullYear();
m = n.getMonth() + 1;
d = n.getDate();
document.getElementById("date").innerHTML = m + "/" + d + "/" + y;
</script>


</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `setTime()`, like this example:

```js
n = new Date();
n.setTime(n.getTime() + (12 * 60 * 60 * 1000)); 
y = n.getFullYear();
m = n.getMonth() + 1;
d = n.getDate();
h = n.getHours();
mi = n.getMinutes();
document.getElementById("date").innerHTML = m + "/" + d + "/" + y + " " + h + ":" + mi;
```

```html
<html>
<font size="+1.5"><p id="date"></p></font>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
Date.prototype.addHours= function(h){
   this.setHours(this.getHours()+h);
   return this;
}
```

Just call addHourse function on `new Date()` and pass number of hours you want to add. For example

```
alert(new Date().addHours(12));
```

Okay. here is the full code.

```js
Date.prototype.addHours = function(h) {
  this.setHours(this.getHours() + h);
  return this;
}

function getFormattedDate(date) {
  var year = date.getFullYear();

  var month = (1 + date.getMonth()).toString();
  month = month.length > 1 ? month : '0' + month;

  var day = date.getDate().toString();
  day = day.length > 1 ? day : '0' + day;

  return month + '/' + day + '/' + year;
}

var date = getFormattedDate(new Date().addHours(12));
var date2 = new Date().addHours(12);
document.getElementById("date").innerHTML = date;
document.getElementById("date2").innerHTML = date2;
```

```html
<html>
<font size="+1.5">
  <p id="date"></p>
</font>
<font size="+1.5">
  <p id="date2"></p>
</font>
</html>
```

This will print the formatted date and date in the default format. You can go with whatever you like.